# CodeIgniter: how to globally disable caching?

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, codeigniter-2, cache-control

My clients's website is done with CodeIgniter.
Problem is: any time I make some changes, I need to empty the 'cache' folder.

I know you can disable cache in a controller:

```
 $this->output->set_header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . ' GMT');('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
    $this->output->set_header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
    $this->output->set_header
```

But how to disable it Globally to the WHOLE website ?

Comment: Browser cache?  Server cache?  Database cache?  See http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/caching.html

Comment: check page roytuts.com/how-to-disable-browser-cache-easily-in-codeigniter/

Comment: I was taking about browser caching php files.

Answer (score 5):

you can globally disable whole website cache by using htaccess

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php)>
   FileETag None
   Header unset ETag
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
   Header set Pragma "no-cache"
   Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php)$>` (including `$`)?

Answer (score 0):

Create the file ***/application/core/My-Output.php*** that has the following lines:

```
class MY_Output extends CI_Output {

function _display_cache(&$CFG, &$URI)
{
    /* Disable Globally */
    return FALSE;

    /* OR - Disable for a specific IP Address */
    if ( ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1') || (eregi("192.168.", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    /* OR - disable based on a cookie value */
    if ( (isset($_COOKIE['nocache'])) && ( $_COOKIE['nocache'] > 0 ) )
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    /* Call the parent function */
    return parent::_display_cache($CFG,$URI);
}
```

This will override the global output handler in your CodeIgniter application in any way you desire.